# Code completion Netbeans 7.2 Mac

Tags: netbeans, code-completion

I'm using Netbeans 7.2 on a Mac and have a question about code completion. Everything seems to work until the moment I want to insert the selected method. When I'm inside a PHP class and I type:

```
$this->
```

...or when I press CTRL-SPACE, then a list of available properties and methods appears. When I select one and press ENTER, the options disappear and nothing is inserted. Double clicking an option also doesn't work, same behaviour. TAB doesn't work either.

Is this normal behaviour and what should I do get something inserted?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoEopKYPh_g

...I see ENTER should work. Any idea why it doesn't work for me?

Comment: After restarting Netbeans, ENTER did work.. Problem kind of solved, probably some glitch.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting Netbeans, ENTER did work. Problem kind of solved, probably some glitch.

Comment: If it's solved, please accept your own answer (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)